# Java compareTo not working as I have intended

Tags: java

I am trying to compare java sentences with commandline input. If I give it multiple words such as

```
Cox jerry bridges alpine rollin
```

It should print out alpine (alphabetically the first one) , but it is not doing that. I would like it to print out the alphabetically first command line argument

Any idea why this program is not working?

```
package Min;

public class Min {

public Min(String[] args)
{

    String temp;
    if (args.length >0)
        temp = args[0];
    else
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("need command line arg");
    for(String k : args)
    {
        int i = k.compareTo(temp);
        if ( i > 0) //k > temp
        {
            temp = k;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Min(args);//Test1 new();
}
```

}

Comment: Mind elaborating on what it's _supposed_ to do?

Comment: And how would you expect this to work?....

Comment: It should print out the first one alphabetically

Comment: Which one does it print?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Is it printing out the last one alphabetically ("rollin")? Have you read the docs?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems: You are finding the maximum, not the minimum, and alphabetically means ignoring case, which `compareTo` does not do.

1. Reverse the comparison to find the minimum.

   ```
   if (i < 0)
   ```
2. Use [the `compareToIgnoreCase` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) to compare your strings alphabetically.

   ```
   int i = k.compareToIgnoreCase(temp);
   ```